# how to get ExePath/MainClassPath/MainJarPath of java App at runtime?

Tags: java, path, program-entry-point

The "Path of the running EXE" is well defined for Windows Applications written in C#, C++, VB, etc.

-
Java Applications on Windows are not "EXE-Applications" but a class-file or a jar-file is started rather than an EXE-file.
So for java Applications the term "ExePath" should be translated to "MainClassPath" or to "JarPath" resp.

-
In some cases a programmer needs to know the physical Path of the Application's jar or MainClass.
(e.g. when you develop a large project both in java and in c# with identical classes and identical methods)

-
thanks to other stackoverflow users this statement does the job:

```
String exePath = URLDecoder.decode(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(), "UTF-8")
```

### and now comes my question:

If I put the same code into any helper/utils jar-library then it will return the path of the helperlib.jar, it will NOT return the path of my MainClass/AppJar !

-

So the final `getExePath()` helper method should look something like:

```
return(URLDecoder.decode(Thread.currentThread().getStartingThread().getMainClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(), "UTF-8"));
```

(if there only were methods like `getStartingThread()` and `getMainClass()` in java ...)

-

### please, point me to the final solution, how can I implement these steps:

- get the starting Thread
- get the Main Class of the starting Thread
- get the Path of the Main Class

Answer (score 0):

if I get you right, just put the method with a parameter of the desired class into your helperlib-class ...

e.g.:

```
public static String getExePath(Object main) {

        String path = "";

        try {
            path = URLDecoder.decode(main.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return path;
}
```

then you can call it e.g. from inside your main-jar with the parameter 'this' ...

```
System.out.println("AppPath:\n" + helperlib.getExePath(this));
```

... and you got the path of the class specified in you parameter

hope it helps and sorry for my bad english ... ;)

Comment: Hi dagreen!

This idea is clear.

Correction: you cannot pass "this" because main()
is static. This works: helperlib.getExePath(new main()).

But is still not a solution!

Who could know which low level method - maybe in 22nd depth level - will one time need to call getExePath?

Maybe metod a() calles b() and b calles c() and c calles d() and so on and Method r() calls getExePath().

No programmer would like to reorganize all methods to 
pass the main class to ANY of his methods ...
just because some low level method might probably
need the getExePath() call in future ...